# Undefined Method error in Ruby class

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I'm trying to write a simple class for an orange tree... but I'm getting this error: pine_orangetree.rb:11:in `oneYearPasses': undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

When I call the oneYearPasses method... Why is that?

```
class OrangeTree

    def initalize
        @height = 0
        @oranges = 0
    end



    def oneYearPasses
        @height += 2
        @oranges = 0

        if @height > 7
            @oranges += 10
        end

        if @height < 30
            puts "Another year has passed..."   
        else
            puts "The orange tree died..."
        end     
    end

    def height
        puts "The tree is #{@height} inches tall."
    end

    def countTheOranges
        puts "There are #{@oranges} on the tree."
    end

    def pickAnOrange
        @oranges -= 1
        puts "You picked an orange."
        puts "There are #{@oranges} left."
    end


end

tree1 = OrangeTree.new
tree1.oneYearPasses
tree1.height
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the word `initalize`. It should be `initialize`.

And because of the typo, the `initalize` method is not called when the object is created, and hence the instance variable `@height` is not defined on creation. And you cannot call `+=` on an object that does not exist yet.

Also as a side note, you shouldn't be adding too many blank lines out of the blue. This is against the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: WOW. LOL Sorry about that! This what makes programming crazy frustrating sometimes. xD Thank you!

Comment: @sickcodeworm You're welcome :) probably you need to mark this as accepted solution.